# Crop Intent Not Working in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a problem regarding cropping image in android studio, whenever I run this cropping code on my device or any other One-plus device, it runs efficiently. But other devices like Redmi, Samsung, Motorola, crash after reaching this cropping part. if I comment out the function call to the cropping function, it runs smoothly on all devices but at cost of non-availability of cropping

```
public void ImageCropFunction(Uri uri) {

        // Image Crop Code
        try {
            Intent CropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"plz, Crop the Required part",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            CropIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
            CropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            CropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 1024);
            CropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 1024);
            CropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            CropIntent.putExtra("return-uri", uri.toString());
            startActivityForResult(CropIntent, 222);
        }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you ok with an library?

Comment: `crash after reaching this cropping part.` what does the crash say ?

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal yes, but it should be easy to integrate, as already my image picking and click code in integrated.

Comment: @a_local_nobody the error doesnt comes on the device in the android studio installs the app, but if i send the apk to my friends and they run it, they get the error. The app crashes and a toast is generated saying "Editing is not supported for this image", where i never integrated such toast in the app

Comment: I have added the answer with implementation.

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal thank you so much!!, I'll implement it in my code.

Comment: Please click the tick ✅ beside my answer. Thanks

Comment: you can pass `this`

Comment: and for context you can pass `getContext()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What to use

---

You can use [uCrop](https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop) library.

### Implemention

---

Make sure you have this line in your `settings.gradle`

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

Add it to your `build.gradle`.

```
implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6'
```

Then you should add it to your manifest

```
<activity
    android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

### How to use

---

You can crop a image like this

```
UCrop.of(yourImageUri, whereToSaveYourCroppedImageUri)
    .withAspectRatio(16, 9) // you can change the aspect ratio.
    .withMaxResultSize(maxWidth, maxHeight) // you can add a custom result height for the image. eg 512 X 512
    .start(context); // enter the context and the crop will start.
```

### Get the result

---

You can fetch the result in the `onActivityResult` like this

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == UCrop.REQUEST_CROP) {
        final Uri resultUri = UCrop.getOutput(data);
        // crop is successful
    } else if (resultCode == UCrop.RESULT_ERROR) {
        final Throwable cropError = UCrop.getError(data);
        // crop failed
    }
}
```

### Output

---

[View the output gif from here](https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop/blob/develop/preview.gif)

Comment: please update this result as onActivityResult is deprecated

Comment: Thanks for bringing it to my concern @DiooB. But, the library is just giving me some issues with the new method which made me feel safe not to change it

Answer (score 1):

[Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There is no requirement for any device to support that undocumented `Intent`, let alone with those undocumented extras. There are [dozens of libraries for image cropping](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45?sort=created). Please use one.

Comment: which is the best library , u suggest that is easy to integrate, without altering the image picking and clicking code. I can make the uri of the image available, to the library

Comment: @Atharv: I have not had to use any library for this in several years, sorry.